# First digit after the decimal of a randomly generated number

Tags: python

I am new to coding in Python, and I am struggling with a code that is supposed to give me the first digit after the decimal of a randomly generated number. So for example:

Input: 1.79
Output: 7

I currently have a code that partially works, but whenever a number has no decimal, for example 10, I want the code to give 0 as output, but I can't get it to work. My code:

```
''''decimal_number = (number - int (number))
print (str (decimal_number) [2])'''
```

It gives me the following error message when I try to input a number that has no decimals:

"Exception IndexError was raised but not expected: string index out of range"

Comment: Integer values do not have a point assigned in Python opposed to floating numbers. The easiest fix is to cast your decimal number to a float. I.e. decimal_number = float(number - int(number)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
input_data = '1.79'
n = float(input_data)  # convert to float
second_digit = int(10 * n) % 10
print(second_digit)
#>>> 7
s = str(second_digit)  # convert back to string, if necessary
print(s)
#>>> '7'
```

for input_data = '18', the output is '0'

Comment: For `input_data = '0.8999999999999999'`, your output is `9` instead of `8`.